# How do you remember user choices from a select menu using PHP?

Tags: php, html, validation

**Beginner here.** I want my user choice from a select menu to be remembered. I have that part down. But now, it is not validating correctly (it was before). How do I fix this?

Here is my code for validating:

```
<?php
  $color = $_POST["color"];

  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    if($_POST["color"] == 0) {
      $errors[] = "Select a color option.";
    }
```

Here is the HTML form with the select list and the php for remembering selection:

```
<h3>MP5 Information</h3>
<span>Color:</span>
<select name="color"id="color">
  <option value="">- Select color -</option>
  <option value="sapphire"<?php echo $color == 'sapphire' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?
  >>Sapphire</option>
  <option value="amethyst"<?php echo $color == 'amethyst' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?
  >>Amethyst</option>
  <option value="rose"<?php echo $color == 'rose' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?
  >>Rose</option>
  <option value="topaz"<?php echo $color == 'topaz' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?
  >>Topaz</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how it was working before, but your condition will not work:

```
'sapphire' == 0
```

for example [evaluates to `true`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GLEhXy).

You probably want something like:

```
if (empty($_POST["color"])) {
```

And also note @PleaseWait's answer about the closing tags.

Answer (score 10):

You codes contain syntax error. `PHP` close tag should be `?>`. You have a new line between `?` and `>`. Fix it first, also enclose the condition by parenthesis.

```
<select name="color" id="color">
    <option value="">- Select color -</option>
    <option value="sapphire"<?php echo ($color == 'sapphire') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Sapphire</option>
    <option value="amethyst"<?php echo ($color == 'amethyst') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Amethyst</option>
    <option value="rose"<?php echo ($color == 'rose') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Rose</option>
    <option value="topaz"<?php echo ($color == 'topaz') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Topaz</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The OP does have the closing `?>`, they're just broken up. Notice the `>>Sapphire` and the others with the `?` at the end of them? `: ''; ?` - Edit: Just as you said. Sorry, long day +1

Answer (score 2):

```
//First make sure its not empty.



 > 123 
Etc...
```

Then add condition to every option

And so on for all options. Remember to xahge condition to same value of each option.

Please not that `<?=` is enabled even if php short opening is disabled in our php.INI.

Cheers